# How to check if a tuple key is in a dict with O(1) time?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I'm trying to implement a hash table/hash map in Python.

Say I'm using tuples as keys like this:

```
hashTable = {}
node = [1, 2, 3]

print(hashTable[tuple(node)]) # throws an error
hashTable[tuple(node)] = True
print(hashTable[tuple(node)]) # prints TRUE
```

I want to check if elements exist in the hashTable before adding it. I have tried initializing the dictionary with all `False` values.

```
hashTable = {}
for i in range(1000):
    hashTable[i] = False
```

So this creates a hash table of size 1000 with every slot set to FALSE. But if I try to check if a non-existent element is in the hashTable:

```
print(hashTable[tuple(node)])
```

I get the same error as before.

How does one go about doing this? I think this would work iterating through the dict with `in` but doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of using a hash table in the first place?

Comment: "I think this would work iterating through the dict with in but doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of using a hash table in the first place?" No, why would you think it would work that way??? The way to efficiently check membership in a dict is to use `key in my_dict`.

Comment: **All** dictionary key look-ups are `O(1)` (assuming you don't write one of your own). Also note that `in` does not iterate the dictionary.

Comment: Your instantiation of `hashTable` creates a Python dictionary of the form `int: bool` which implies that when you access an element inside it you'd do `hashTable[SOME_NUMBER]` so why are you looking up a tuple?

Comment: In addition to the great answers below, if you actually need non-existing keys to be initialized with a default value, use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) rather than inserting all possible values.

Comment: @martineau Not really **all**. Hash calculations can take arbitrarily long, hash collisions can make searching linear time, and matching hashes need to be confirmed with an equality check, so it also depends on how fast the objects compare. (Of course in most cases I also think of it as O(1), just saying since you emphasized that so much).

Comment: @martineau A little fun: Building a dict from just 1000 existing ints can take [more than a second](https://tio.run/##RY7BCoMwEETv@Yo9ZtsiES9F9EtKkVhjXWo2IYkHvz5VK3ROM485PL@myXF19yHnMTgLiayhBGS9C@lc4lxxjUIwtFAqpYTeykNurJh0nDri0RXWDcu8RLgAIVxBltA0x1spFLBndAEIiCFofhvJ@BQ76v6owvq4@kCc5M9Aztr2g65hoFcqdtGPWaPUeANebG9CWyLm/AU) :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy: Sure there's some variance and different amounts of overhead but that's not how [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) is measured. I'd also like to point out that all I said was that look-ups were on that order, not building them — which is the subject of this question (i.e. checking for membership).

Comment: @martineau Not sure why you're saying that's not how time complexity is measured. And [Python Time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) acknowledges it's only O(n) (also not quite correct, only considers the number-of-collisions aspect). Building involves the same things as lookups, but ok, [int key lookup taking 0.004 seconds](https://tio.run/##RU7NDoMgGLvzFN8R9mMgXhajT2KMwYHziwIG8ODTO3Am66lt2qbrHidny9fqj2P0zkBEozECmtX5eClyqbAHQiw0IDjnRCbS0uQVkwxTj3Z0hXFqW7YAN0AGd6AC6vpMc84IZIzOAwJa8NJ@NLWsIyoNKXzHIh@Y9R6oZGROpmyfoiO50f8bJavOpdWjjfR3kC7SDEpWMOeceoDdzKB9Ixg7ji8).

Comment: @KellyBundy: Perhaps you only looked at the first section of the [TimeComplexity - Python Wikiy](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) page which is for **list**, further down in the table for **dict**, it shows the average case for `x in d` is O(1). Same for "Set Item" and the greater part of the other operations as well.

Comment: @martineau Yes, for **average**. But that's not what were talking about. And right next to it you can see the O(n). Looks like you're misunderstanding/misrepresenting what average means.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Why do you think we are talking about worst case?

Comment: @martineau Because you said "**All**" (emphasis yours). Which includes worst cases. I think I just realized why you were talking about "some variance" and complaining about me building instead of just looking up, though. You're thinking about the *occasional* high cost when the dict resizes and reinserts everything, right? If that were the only high cost, I probably wouldn't have spoken up at all. What I've shown is how easy it is to cause the worst case for *every* operation. My ints all have the exact same hash, effectively turning the lookup into a linear search. When I look...

Comment: ...(continuing) up that 1000th key, the dict goes through all of the first 999 keys and compares it with all of them. So essentially we actually *should* look at that table of the `list`complexities for that.

Comment: @KellyBundy: All I meant was overall one could expect the average-case behavior of O(1) for any kind of look-up (for a container of any size, which is what time-complexity measures).

Comment: @martineau Ok, that sounds alright (except you can't expect it for the processing-values-from-a-hacker kind of look-up :-). Just be aware that that's not what "**All** dictionary key look-ups are O(1)" came across like. (Rereading that comment I also just noticed your "Also note that `in` does not iterate the dictionary", which is also not really true, as it does do a kind of iteration (over the places in its hash table where the key might be). Though in general that iteration is short, unlike the *full* iteration I caused).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a key is similar to, but not necessarily the same as checking if it exists. To check if a key is in a dictionary, use `dict.__contains__` via the `in` operator. To check if it is missing, use the `not in` operator:

```
key = tuple(node)
if key not in hashTable:
    hashTable[key] = value
```

That being said, a totally valid way to check for containment can be by attempting access:

```
key = tuple(node)
try:
    # attempt to use hashTable[key]
except KeyError:
    # Do something with missing key
```

The advantage of doing it this way when both paths are needed is that you only need to access the dictionary once rather than twice.

Try to avoid calling `tuple(node)` over and over: it's not free. If you can, generate `node` as a `tuple`, do so. If not, perform the conversion once and use the converted value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator to determine membership in a dictionary:

e.g.

```py
if tuple(node) in hashTable:
     x = hashTable[tuple(node)]
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the key and in case it is not in de dictionary yet, return a default value as may be `None`:

```py
x = hashTable.get(node, default=None)
```